# Creating new Object from args given through cmd line gives me OutOfMemoryError thrown from UncaughtExceptionhandler

Tags: java, args, cmdline-args

I cannot find out why the above error thrown. It works fine when I only enter 2 arguments (e.G 22.5 km), using more than that (20.5 km 400 ft) gives the error.

Here is the code:

```
if (args.length > 0)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i = +2)
    {
        lengthsCollection.add(new Length(Double.parseDouble(args[i]), args[i+1]));    
    }
}
```

class Length is working fine everywhere else

```
public class Length {
    private double valueM;
    private String unitM;

    public Length(double value, String unit)  
    {
        this.valueM = value;
        this.unitM = unit;
    }
```

Can someone help me out? I thought my code should work if the user inputs properly (length + unit pairs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This iteration:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i = +2)
```

is executed for ever when `args.length > 2` because `i` remains `2` for ever. Hence the memory error.

What you need is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
```